# The definition of an open set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can someone help me to understand this definition of an open set?

Definition: $S$ is an open set if for each    $p$ belonging to $S$, there exists an $r>0$ such that  $d(p,q) < r$   ($q$ belongs to $S$)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

For every point $p$, you want a small neighborhood around $p$ that is entirely within $S$. This is given by the points $q$ in your definition (which is correctly stated as "[...] there exists an $r>0$ such that $q\in S$ for every $q$ where $d(p,q)<r$").

Comment: There could also be an implicit "imples" between "d(p,q) < r" and "(q belongs to S)" in OP's formulation. Nevertheless, the statement needed some fixing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the established use of parentheses in displayed equations your "definition" says:

$S$ is an open set if for each $p$ belonging to $S$, there exists an $r>0$ such that  $d(p,q) < r$  for all $q\in S$.

This sentence in reality describes a *bounded set*. Replace it by:

$S$ is an *open set* if for each $p$ belonging to $S$, there exists an $r>0$ such that $q\in S$ for all $q$ with  $d(p,q) < r$.

The underlying philosophy is the following: In a topological space $X$ to each point $p$ are associated its *neighborhoods*. These are subsets of $X$ containing $p$ and all points "sufficiently near" $p$. A metric $d$ allows to handle this notion of "sufficiently near" in a simple way. An *open set*  $S\subset X$ is then a set which together with each point  $p\in S$ contains a full, maybe "small", neighborhood of $p$.